# How to get a list of valid addresses?

Tags: testing, data

I need to get a list of valid addresses in 4 or 5 clusters (cities) in both the UK and US. It's to generate sample data for an application that will do geolocation and searching. At the moment I'm generating the addresses more or less randomly, which means I hit postcodes that don't exist and obviously the street and number never match the postcode.

Any recommendations on how to programatically obtain a list of addresses to build test data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random valid addresses are easy. Go to the website for a big organization, like the post office, McDonald's, Federal Express, and scrape store locations from their webpage.

You could also use local government sites for schools, recreation centers, red light cameras...